# How can I move a div while revealing text under it using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to jquery and javascript. I was wonering if someone can help me understand how this works. 
I have a div with an image and when i hover over it i want it to move up (got this part working  just fine) but now I want to display text underneath the image once the div is moved up I'm trying to use .toggle, but it only works with the first image and not the rest. It also already displays the text (even though my css is display hidden for the text) and then makes it disappear and then reappear on the hover I've commented out my second approach which pretty much did the same thing! :(
thank you very much in advanced!

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    //move the thumbnail up
    $('.art-thumb').hover(
        function(){
            console.log('it works!');
            $(this).animate({bottom:'50px'},
                $('#artist-statement').toggle('slow', function(){})
                );
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({bottom:'0'});
        }
        );
                console.log('it knows it should move');

    //display the artstatement under it
        // $('.art-thumb').mouseover(function(){
        //     $('#artist-statement').toggle('slow', function(){
        //         //toggle finished.
        //     });
        // });

    });
```

I've pasted my code here http://jsfiddle.net/veHq3/

Comment: I updated your fiddle to load jQuery 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

though question is bit unclear... assuming this is what you want..

**html**

```
<div class="art-thumb"></div>
<p class="artist-statement">artist statement1</p>
<br/>
<div class="art-thumb"></div>
<p class="artist-statement">artist statement2</p>
<br/>
<div class="art-thumb"></div>
<p class="artist-statement">artist statement3</p>
<br/>
```

**jquery**

```
$('document').ready(function () {
//move the thumbnail up
$('.art-thumb').hover(
function () {
    console.log('it works!');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        bottom: '50px'
    }, function () {
        $(this).next('.artist-statement').slideDown();
    });
},
function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        bottom: '0'
    }, function () {
        $(this).next('.artist-statement').slideUp();
    });
});
console.log('it knows it should move');


});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veHq3/7/)

**explanation:**

use the callback function of animation to make sure the `slideUp` and `slideDown` work after the animation is complete. **i changed your ID to Class to make sure IDs is  unique( having multiple elements with same id is invalid)**. Using `slideDown` on mouseenter to show and `slideUp` on mouseleave to hide the corresponding div. `toggle()` is deprecated in latest version of jquery.

and as @Pete Scott stated.. `display:hidden` should be `display:none`

**things to be careful.**

since i am using `next()`..`$(this).next('.artist-statement').slideUp();` here, this search for element whose class is artist-statement next to `$(this)` i.e `<div class="art-thumb">`..so you need to make sure the artist statement `<p>` is always right next to `<div class="art-thumb">` for this to work. (though there are other ways to make this work, unless you provide us with your HTML markup).

it would have been really easy if you had provided your HTML markup.. but i think this should get you started.. :)..

**updated**

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veHq3/11/)

Comment: Hi, thank you this is a lot better than what i had. Unfortunately now i cant get the text to show under the div (i implimented your code and changed my ids to classes is this because the css is display:none;?

Comment: did you check the updated fiddle.. anyways `text to show under the div` i am not getting you ??

Comment: yeah your fiddle works great, im not sure what the update is though because it looks the like the same thing i originally posted? For some reason though on my actual code it doesnt display the text at all it just moves the div up

Comment: How do i get the text to be under the div if the divs are next to eachother? if i use a br tag then the divs arent lined up

Answer (score 1):

Your css in incorrect. "display:hidden;" should be either "display:none;" or "visibility:hidden;" (likely the former).

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you suggest how i would have the effect work on all the divs as opposed to just one?

Comment: Update your fiddle to include the multiple div and any other necessary elements and I'll certainly take a look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/veHq3/10/ Thank you, ive updated it the <p> tag should be under the div but i think you get the idea lol :P I really appreciate it!

Comment: Ah, you can't have multiple elements with the same id. We'll need to modify your DOM structure a bit. I'll fork your fiddle and show a working implementation.

Comment: @bipen has the right answer, and as a bonus he avoided toggle() which has been obsoleted recently. You should accept his answer (assuming his implementation meets your needs).